# Sybase Drivers for Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, drivers, sap-ase

We are migrating from Delphi 6 to Delphi 2010,earlier we were using BDE engine to connect to Sybase Database from Delphi 6. We found out that Delphi 2010 does not support BDE.

We are trying with dbexpress but we are not able to catch the exception(raise error) thrown by Sybase.

Could  you please let me know if there is any other driver except dbexpress to connect to Sybase Database from Delphi 2010.

Thanks.

Regards,
AS

Comment: Assuming you got Delphi 2010 pro, you might be interested to know that an upgrade to Delphi XE Enterprise is on at a reduced price right now. That would get you the dbExpress connection to Sybase, which you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a workaround:

1. Install Delphi 6
2. Update BDE to the latest available version (there should be some updates on Embarcadero site, I hope)
3. Install Delphi 2010

IIRC the available SQL Links should not be removed (otherwise it would break the older version), and they should still work in Delphi 2010. But that's really a stopgap try.

Devart's [UniDac](http://www.devart.com/unidac/) can connect to Sybase without using dbExpress, but I never used it.

Comment: @user637761: What Connection?

Comment: Thanks..its working fine..i didnt got many issues..but a bit manageble issues we are facing..:)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/) to connect to:

- Sybase SQL Anywhere (AnyDAC native driver)
- Sybase Adaptive Server (AnyDAC ODBC bridge).

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your real problem is that you have the Professional version of Delphi rather than Enterprise. As far as I know, BDE can still be used with Delphi 2010.

With Delphi 6 the Professional version allowed connections to remote databases.  Somewhere between Delphi 6 and Delphi 2010 that policy was changed.

Anyway, you really need to give up on BDE and move forward.

*Edit: (jeroen)*
The BDE for relational access (aka the `BDE SQL Links technology`) [has been deprecated since 2002](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28688), about 2 years after the [introduction of dbExpress in Kylix and Delphi 6](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/22495).

Comment: Most likely, the BDE thing got someone else to do a down-vote; maybe explain the BDE deprecation in a bit more detail (I think the BDE client/server drivers have been removed since Delphi 2005 and up; it is fine - but still deprecated - to use the BDE for Paradox/xBase stuff) or point to SO questions covering the BDE. If you do, +1.

Comment: From what I understand, no wrong at all. My install of XE does not have Sybase drivers. Perhaps they were removed in some Delphi version as Jeroen says. BDE can use ODBC and that might work for OP. Never used it myself.

Comment: BDE can still be used in Delphi XE.  I'm not sure if it includes all the drivers in the XE installer, but if you have a previous Delphi version or the BDE 5.x installer alone, you can still use the same drivers for any database you want.

Comment: Professional version never came with BDE SQL Links (but Interbase, maybe) which allow to connect to the supported RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Sybase drivers for dbExpress is included in Enterprise version of Delphi. If that is not an option you can use dbGO (ADO) that is included in Professional.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ZEOSLIB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zeoslib/) which contains SyBase connectivity, along with many other SQL dbs.

As far as I can see, it requires you to remove your Query/Table objects and replace them with its own Table and Query replacement objects, but then, so would moving from BDE to ADO/dbGo or dBExpress.

And you really should get the BDE out of your application. It's dead as a doornail.